# Threat detected in geth/chaindata: Mirror-4130

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, chaindata

Virus detection just picked up a threat, called [Mirror-4130](https://www.sophos.com/en-us//threat-center/threat-analyses/viruses-and-spyware/Mirror-4130.aspx) in `~/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata/6902332.ldb`

Has anyone else seen this, and/or can explain a bit how the `chaindata` directory works? Particularly why I may be getting a virus warning

Possibly related, Mist has been having an impossible time catching up on blocks. Is it possible `chaindata` was corrupted somehow?

[image: Sophos threat warning Mirror-4130 Ethereum Geth]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the threat you've linked to, it's a "DOS Executable Virus" from 1994. It is highly likely this is of no harm to a modern system and is likely a [false positive from Sophos](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/security-world/2017/09/explained-false-positives/%20%22false%20positive%20from%20Sophos%22.).

Geth chaindata is stored as a sequence of [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb) databases (see the .ldb extension). If a byte sequence in the database matches a signature (binary pattern or fingerprint) used by Sophos's antivirus heuristics, Sophos will not be able to tell the difference.